# A way to find out what data bytes in memory are?

Tags: c++, memory, types

I've been trying to learn about strings and how they are constructed in memory in C++.
And I was just wondering if there was a way to take a memory address and find out what type of data it is?

Or alternatively be able to take a class and sort of 'reverse engineer' it to find out what other types that class is made of? And the order in which they are stored in memory.

I only ask this because I've just been messing around with strings just trying to learn about them and was surprised that they were 28 bytes and wanted to find out what it was made of.
Although i'd love to know if there is just a general method for any class or type not just strings.

Comment: nope. in memory its just bits.

Comment: That being said, if you look at the way the data changes, or its relationship to other more obvious data, you can frequently determine what data type it is (even if you are wrong) through common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of things in C++, or any compiled language for that matter, which are termed "implementation specific", something that means in one sense "arbitrary" and in another "none of your business".

As far as memory is concerned, bytes are bytes, they have values, but unless you have a pointer or a reference you're really not able to deduce what you're looking at. C++ does have [Runtime Type Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) or RTTI that may be available for some things, but not others.

If you're curious about how a string, or any class, is composed you'll need to dig through the Standard Library implementation you're using, though this code is often highly quirky and convoluted, with performance a far more pressing priority than readability.

Some languages like Ruby maintain a very clear index of what's stored in memory that can be worked backwards, but C++ is nothing like that. A lot of this information is deliberately discarded in the name of performance, that the compiler can and will optimize much of this out depending on how it's engaged. This means a lot of things that you'd presume are laid out clearly end up being very hazy and confused.

Answer (score 0):

> And I was just wondering if there was a way to take a memory address and find out what type of data it is?

Not really.

In a Van Neumann machine the meaning of a memory location depends upon the instructions being executed.

Any given sequence of bytes could be interpreted as string, integer, floating value or even as an instruction.

In a virtual memory system, there are hints. A memory page could be read only/read-write or execute/noexecute that would give hints about the usage.